# Submitting a form in Django doesn't execute the correct function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I have tried to create a simple form of registration with 'POST' method, and then at `views.py` I tried this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth

# Create your views here.
def register(request):

if request.POST:
    first_name = request.POST["first_name"]
    last_name = request.POST["last_name"]
    username = request.POST["username"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    password = request.POST["password1"]
    password2 = request.POST["password2"]

    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=username, 
        password=password,
        email=email, 
        first_name=first_name, 
        last_name=last_name
    )
    user.save()
    return redirect("/")

else:
    return render(request, "register.html")
```

to prevent the page from going to the same url again like '..../register/register' since i have been using the same file 'register.html' for submiting data and fetching the page :

```
    <form action="register" method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <br>
    First_Name : <br> <input type="text" maxlength="30" 
    placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required> 
    <br>
    Last_Name : <br> <input type="text" maxlength="30" 
    placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required> 
    <br>
    User_Name : <br> <input type="text" maxlength="30" 
    placeholder="User Name" name="username" required> 
    <br>
    Email : <br> <input type="email" placeholder="Email" 
    name="email"  required>
    <br>
    Password :<br> <input type="password" maxlength="30" 
    placeholder="Password" name="password1" required>

    Confirm_Password :<br> <input type="password" maxlength="30" 
    placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password2" required> 
    <hr>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

this is my project file urls :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
  path('', include('website.urls')),
  path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The problem is when I click submit... it doesn't execute the code inside `if request.method == 'POST'`. it returns another URL of the same page. Like "....accounts/register/register" which is doesn't exist.

Any idea what may cause the problem. Thank you

Comment: what is your problem exactly? you didnt mention it in question

Comment: Mention your exact error.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed indentation in your `def register(request):`

change your view like this:

```
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password1")
        password2 = request.POST.get("password2")
    
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, 
            password=password,
            email=email, 
            first_name=first_name, 
            last_name=last_name
        )
        user.save()
        return redirect("/")
    
    else:
        return render(request, "register.html")
```

Comment: i have tried it before.. but still not working

Comment: the problem is when i click submit.. it doesn't execute the code inside ' if request.method == 'POST' '... it returns an other url of the same page .. Like : "....accounts/register/register" which is doesn't exist.. I hope you get it

Comment: how ? i didn't get what you mean !!

Comment: edited the answer. Just copy the view code into your views.py.

Comment: I've just figured out what was the problem.. I have changed ' path( 'register/ ', views.register, name = "register" )'  with  --> ' url( ' register/', views.register, name = "register") ' in urls.py file..
thank you for your help .. I appreciate it